# Grep the word inside double quote

Tags: tcl

How can I extract a word inside a double quote inside a file?
e.g.

```
variable "xxx"
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading a text file into Tcl is just this:

```
set fd [open $filename]
set data [read $fd]        ;# Now $data is the entire contents of the file
close $fd
```

To get the *first* quoted string (under some assumptions, notably a lack backslashed double quote characters inside the double quotes), use this:

```
if {[regexp {"([^""]*)"} $data -> substring]} {
    # We found one, it's now in $substring
}
```

(Doubling up the quote in the brackets is totally unnecessary — only one is needed — but it does mean that the highlighter does the right thing here.)

The simplest method of finding *all* the quoted strings is this:

```
foreach {- substring} [regexp -inline -all {"([^""]*)"} $data] {
    # One of the substrings is $substring at this point
}
```

Notice that I'm using the same regular expression in each case. Indeed, it's actually good practice to factor such REs (especially if repeatedly used) into a variable of their own so that you can “name” them.

---

Combining all that stuff above:

```
set FindQuoted {"([^""]*)"}

set fd [open $filename]
foreach {- substring} [regexp -inline -all $FindQuoted [read $fd]] {
    puts "I have found $substring for you"
}
close $fd
```

Comment: You can use external programs like grep or sed to do the searching, but then you're less portable. The above code works on _any_ platform that supports a sufficiently-modern Tcl. (If you're using anything before 8.4, ***upgrade first*** please!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and it works.  However, i am not really understand - in {- substring} and ^"" in [^""].  Pls elaborate more on it.  Can you recommend some articles about - and ^"" and so that i can understand. As far as i know about ^, it is just a complement.  When use with ^"", i have no idea what does it means.  I have tried with ^", but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

#### Internal Matching

If you're just looking for a regular expression, then you can use TCL's capture groups. For example:

```
set string {variable "xxx"}
regexp {"(.*)"} $string match group1
puts $group1
```

This will return `xxx`, discarding the quotes.

#### External Matching

If you want to match data in a file without having to handling reading the file into TCL directly, you can do that too. For example:

```
set match [exec sed {s/^variable "\(...\)"/\1/} /tmp/foo]
```

This will call sed to find just the parts of the match you want, and assign them to a TCL variable for further process. In this example, the *match* variable is set to `xxx` as above, but is operating on an external file rather than a stored string.

Comment: The first case will work here, but will fail if the string contains something like `variable1 "xxx" variable2 "yyy"` -- you'll match too much. The second case, you're assuming there are exactly 3 characters in quotes.

Answer (score -1):

When you just want to find with `grep` all words in quotes in a file and do something with the words, you do something like this (in a shell):

```
grep -o '"[^"]*"' | while read word
do
   # do something with $word
   echo extracted: $word
done
```

Comment: I believe the submitter is looking for a `tcl` answer.